# drawing points evenly distributed on a circle

Tags: php, math, geometry, gd

i want to get the coordinates of n points on a circle with the diameter of x

i tried this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$img = @imagecreate(900, 900)
or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
for($i=0;$i<=360;$i+=10)
{
$x = round(cos($i)*400)+450;
$y = round(sin($i)*400)+450;
imagefilledellipse($img, $x, $y, 3, 3, $red);
}
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

but there seems to be an error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8VYn.jpg

school and math and sin&cos is long ago ... so i would be happy if someone could give me a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically just use the deg2rad function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.deg2rad.php

So change your cos and sin calls to this:

```
$x = round(cos(deg2rad($i))*400)+450;
$y = round(sin(deg2rad($i))*400)+450;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP trigonometric functions accept radian values, so you should multiply values of $i by Pi/180.

Comment: i don't know radian values ... sorry

Comment: Check out the wikipedia page for a better understanding.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian
But to cut it short, the radian value of an angle is Pi/180 times its degree value, that's why a simple multiplication solves your conversion problem.